# SQL Server stored procedure returns an error when run on a web page

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run query in sql then it runs successfully but when it's run in web page then it throws an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

The stored procedure:

```
    IF (@Mode='CurrentList') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY emp1.Name ASC) AS RowNumber 
           ,emp1.empid 
           ,emp1.Name
           ,(SELECT emp2.Address FROM (SELECT Address,ID,Time, Number=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Time DESC) FROM EMP_table2) emp2 join [EMP_table1] emp1  ON emp1.ID=emp2.ID WHERE Number = 1) as Address
          ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, emp2.Time , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM (SELECT ID,Time, Number=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Time DESC) FROM EMP_table2) emp2 join [EMP_table1] emp1 ON emp1.ID=emp2.ID WHERE Number = 1) as Time       
        INTO 
           #CurrentDateList
        FROM 
           [EMP_table1] emp1 
        JOIN 
           [EMP_table3] emp3 ON emp1.Name = emp3.Name  
        WHERE 
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN emp3.StartDate AND emp3.EndDate 

      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #CurrentDateList

      SELECT * FROM #CurrentDateList
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #CurrentDateList
END
```

Comment: does not look like `mysql` code so remove `mysql` tag from the question.

Comment: Your  `ROW_NUMBER()` calls include `PARTITION BY` so it feels like there could easily be more than one row with a `Number` of `1`. But without knowing *your* tables, *your* data, and what parameter values are being supplied, it's difficult for us to point out exactly *where* you're ending up with multiple values.

Comment: If you try this on mysql then use some delimiter(eg.DELIMITER $$) and end your code with semicolons after each statement and end up with the delimiter(

END$$
DELIMITER ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subqueries are joining `emp1` both times, and I don't think this is what you want. I think you want this pattern for your subqueries:

```
 ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, emp2.Time , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
   FROM (SELECT ID,Time, 
          Number=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Time DESC) 
          FROM EMP_table2) emp2 
   WHERE emp1.ID=emp2.ID AND Number = 1) as Time
```